# Why does gedit use too much cpu when minimised?

Tags: gedit, cpu-load

The text editor gedit in ubuntu takes up 30 to 50% of my cpu when I keep it minimised. When I maximise it to use it again, the cpu usage drops to zero. This happens even when gedit is idle without much or any text at all. I tried purging and reinstalling gedit many times. But it doesn't help. I searched online for help. But could not find anybody else with the same problem nor is any bug reported on their site which resembles my issue. Where is the problem? Is it with gedit? Or is it my Ubuntu?

My Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and gedit version is 3.18.3-0ubuntu4

A bug has been reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1679226
and it has been confirmed. Please share any temporary or permanent solution to this issue. I am still struggling with this issue after months.

Comment: Do you have any other information, like opened files (maybe a big one?), Ubuntu/Gedit version? Are you maybe saving something in gedit, may this be a big autosave? And is i/o-usage also high? (You can see this by `iotop`)

Comment: No this happens even when gedit is idle. And there is nothing unusual about the i/o usage. It happens every time I open gedit

Comment: It has been months and I still don't have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since this was asked, but this just happened to me on 22.04.

In my case, the mere act of opening gedit made the fans spin up and the load average spike. I could not type 80 characters before gedit would start slowing down and become unable to keep up with my typing.

However, it was a simple fix:
Menu (at the time of writing, button with three horizontal bars in the top right, just to the right of the "Save" button)
Preferences -> Plugins -
I had to disable the "File Browser" plugin.

Depending on how bad you've got this problem, you may want to disable all of them, which is honestly what I did first. Seeing having them all disabled fixed the problem, I enabled them one after the other until i was able to determine it was in fact the "File Browser" plugin.

No idea why this causes such awful behavior.

I hope this helps someone.